# How I can use a bean variable of Date type in JSF?

Tags: date, jsf, jsf-2

I have a Bean: `FormBean`. In this class I have a `Date` variable of name `fecha`. I want update the fecha value with the JSF page. In this moment I created an auxiliary variable: `fechaString` of String type.

In this momento I have the next code:

```
<b:inputText id = "inputFechaFormulario" required = "true" value = "#{formBean.fechaString}"/>
```

But I want this code:

```
<b:inputText id = "inputFechaFormulario" required = "true" value = "#{formBean.fecha}"/>
```

The problem is: fecha isn't `String`, is `Date`, and I don't know a solution.

Comment: Format your auxiliary string variable to date in your bean.

Comment: How I can format the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `h:inputText` with a `convertDateTime` like this

```
<h:inputText id = "inputFechaFormulario" required = "true" value = "#{formBean.fecha}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
</h:inputText>
```

You can change the date pattern to match the display you want. Thus your value can be a `Date` object and if you submit your form, you will still retrieve a `Date` object

For more information, read this : [f:convertDateTime](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_convertDateTime.html)

Comment: Excelent! Other thing: with new Date(), the page show "01/06/2016}", that is to say, with "}" character, what do I do?

Comment: sorry I forgot a curly brace `}` inside the pattern in my exemple. Just remove it, I will edit my post

Comment: No, thanks. Was the character, excuse me